# python: how to display a image directly from bytes string variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a byte string variable `fig` which I get from another API.

```
print(fig)

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\....'
```

How can I display a picture directly from this variable?

PS: I don't want to store this variable in a PNG file, then use matplotlib to read and show.

I have tried PIL.Image.frombytes
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes however, I don't know which mode(https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) I have to choose. It reports errors when I tried several modes.

Comment: Have you looked at pil?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes however, I don't know which mode I can choose. I tried several ones and report error

Comment: Could you provide the full PNG? Perhaps dump the string to a file and post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

nparr = np.fromstring(img_str, np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(nparr, -1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```